# Excel line up data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a total Excel nub and can't find the answer I'm looking for. Must be easy peasy, but since I'm not into Excel I also don't know what to look for. Sorry if I'm having my question wrong.

I have output in Excel like this:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 1
B 2
B 3
B 4
B 5
B 6
```

and I want it like this:

```
A 1 2 3 4
B 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: make sure you add a header row first before pivoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question is quite complex in a way.
let me explain it more in detail:

[image]

as you see above, we have two columns **A** and **B**, you have text strings in column **A** , these text strings could be repeated. As you see in the example, there are 4 **A**s, 5 **B**s, 3 **C**s 1 **D** and 3 **E**s. In column **B** each one of these strings have different corresponding values. For example, text strings ***B*** in column **A** has *five* corresponding values in column **B**, namely 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, and 16. 

 Now we want a list of ***UNIQUE*** values from column ***A***, and lets say, we put this list in column **C** and then for each of these unique values in column **C** we want to list their corresponding cells in column **B** and put them ***HORIZONTALLY*** in front of each of these unique text strings in column **C**. 

For this you need two kinds of formulas:
***Formula 1 to calculate the list of the unique values in column A*** : 

this goes in **C2**:(leave C1 empty)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$999;MATCH(0;FREQUENCY(IF(EXACT($A$1:$A$999;TRANSPOSE($C$1:C1));MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$999);ROW($A$1:$A$999)); ""); MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$999);ROW($A$1:$A$999))); 0)); "")
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula, and drag and fill down as many as you want in column **C**. 

***Formula 2 to find and list horizontally the values from column B ***

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$999;SMALL(IF($C2=$A$1:$A$999;ROW($A$1:$A$999)-ROW($A$1)+1);COLUMN(A$1)));"")
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula, put this in **D2** and drag and fill down until the last cell of column **C**. then select **D2** to **D6** and drag and fill **horizontally**. You should get all of the corresponding cells in front of each unique item.

***P.S.*** **adjust the formulas to meet your regional settings by replacing** **;** **with** **,**  **I suppose.**

***Finally*** here is **[the link to an example sheet downloadable from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f69vrvhnkq9llm/tranpose_unique_value.xlsx?dl=0)** .

Comment: Hi AHC, thanks a lot for this very clear solution. I'm glad it was more complex than I thought. But that is my lack of Excel knowledge ;) I can work with this, you saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

This is very generic but hopefully will help.

1. Highlight the cells that you want to transpose to.
2. Type the equation..."=TRANSPOSE(B1:B4)" (edit as necessary).
3. While the cells are still highlighted, press "ctrl+shift+enter". (brackets should appear around the equation)
4. Finish editing the cells.
5. Celebrate

Comment: actually this formula gives repetitive values and does not trim the results. it only transposes the data. I explained the way to do this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27116319/4230650)

Comment: Yeah, it was only intended to transpose the data. I didn't have much time so I wrote for what I assumed was giving him trouble. Bravo for the thorough answer though.